# Django: application domain causes invalid hyperlinks generation

Tags: django, web-services, dns

My django app is accessible under somedomain.com/myappname and that causes lots of trouble. Most of them can be bypassed somehow, but when I found out that I can't access objects managing pages with hyperlinks generated by admin panel (since they should be available under somedomain.com/myappname/admin/etcetc and app generates hyperlinks like somedomain.com/admin/etcetc), I started wondering how to make application understand that its base address is not somedomain.com but somedomain.com/myappname. Is there some config variable I need to set up or anything? Well, the easiest way is to change domain to myappname.somedomain.com, but if only I could do that.

Comment: You need to show how you are hosting this site. If you are doing it properly, it just works, so you're clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: It's pretty messy and I don't know all details either. I just took care of writting the app. The company's server administrator takes care of hosting it. He set up nginx somehow that when I run uwsgi script, the app's being hosted and voila.  You say something on his side went wrong?

Comment: The web server is supposed to pass on the `SCRIPT_NAME` header which provides the prefix. You might want to look at the [uwsgi docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html) about that. As a last resort, you can set [`FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#force-script-name) in the Django settings.

Comment: did you set your `site` object value to `somedomain.com/myappname` instead of `somedomain.com` ?

Comment: @kicker86: where do you set this?

Comment: see `site framework`  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/ that defines the `site` object, which is stored in the database, and can be accessed through the `admin` interface